# Invalid namespace in Ext.i18n.Bundle in Extjs 5.1.1

Tags: extjs, localization, namespaces, store

When using [ExtJS 5.1](https://github.com/E-P1983/Ext.i18n.Bundle) I always get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [Ext.ClassManager] Invalid namespace, must be a string  @ext-all-debug.js:8430 
parseNamespace         @ ext-all-debug.js:8430
createNamespaces       @ ext-all-debug.js:8490
(anonymous function)   @ ext-all-debug.js:4450
onBeforeLaunch         @ Bundle.js?_.dc=1476694441934:227
onProfilesReady        @ ext-all-debug.js:54622
constructor            @ ext-all-debug.js:54616
AppTest.$application   @ ext-all-debug.js:7660
(anonymous function)   @ ext-all-debug.js:54856
invoke                 @ ext-all-debug.js:10477
doInvokeAll            @ ext-all-debug.js:10517
invokeAll              @ ext-all-debug.js:10486
unblock                @ ext-all-debug.js:10596
triggerReady           @ ext-all-debug.js:11090
checkReady             @ ext-all-debug.js:11194
load                   @ ext-all-debug.js:10969
require                @ ext-all-debug.js:10882
triggerReady           @ ext-all-debug.js:11065
checkReady             @ ext-all-debug.js:11194
onLoadSuccess          @ ext-all-debug.js:11011
notify                 @ ext-all-debug.js:862
processLoadedEntries   @ ext-all-debug.js:841
notifyRequests         @ ext-all-debug.js:1308
complete               @ ext-all-debug.js:1157
(anonymous function)   @ ext-all-debug.js:1163
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you look at the stack trace, you see that the issue seems to be in Bundle.js, line 227, because that's the first non-sencha line mentioned in the trace:

```
ns = Ext.namespace(me.name);
```

If you try

```
console.log(me.name);
```

you will find that it is `undefined`, because starting with 5.0.0, Sencha has moved more and more towards `getter` and `setter` methods, so your best bet is

```
console.log(me.getName());
```

Comment: That in deed was the issue.. And also including this.initConfig() also helped loading all the configs in the constructor.